# Display Articles in VF

Tags: apex, visualforce, knowledge

My VF Page:

```
   <apex:page controller="ArticleSalesKBController" >

    <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->


  <apex:repeat value="{!SearchResults}" var="article"  >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
        <p class="knowledgebase_heading">
         {!article.id}

          <li><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.KnowledgeArticle.View, 
         article.id)}">{!article.title}</a></li>


        </p>
        <p>{!article.summary}</p>
      </div>
       </div>
      </apex:repeat>

       </apex:page>
```

My Controller:

```
public class ArticleSalesKBController {
    public List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> getSearchResults(){ 
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articleList= [SELECT 
        Id, title, Summary, KnowledgeArticleId
        FROM KnowledgeArticleVersion 
        WHERE (ArticleType= 'Article__kav' and Language = 'en_US')];

    return articleList;
    }
}
```

But I get an error:

> Unable to Access Page The value of a parameter contains a character
>   that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length.
>   Remove the character from the parameter value or reduce the value
>   length and resubmit. If the error still persists, report it to our
>   Customer Support team. Provide the URL of the page you were requesting
>   as well as any other related information.

Comment: when do you get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are not using a standard knowledge:articlelist component:

```
    <knowledge:articleList  articleVar="article" articleTypes="Article__kav">
          <li><a href="{!URLFOR($Action.KnowledgeArticle.View, article.id)}">{!article.title}</a></li>
    </knowledge:articleList>
```

as mentioned in the [visualforce developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_knowledge_articleList.htm)? or do you have a specific use case for following this path?